# Is there a Mac application to search content of .txt files without opening it?

Tags: macos

I have a situation that need to search some specific texts in .txt files, for example, about 100 files on a specific folder. I couldn't open each file and read it.

So I would like to ask whether there is an application that I can use to import all those files and use a search feature to search the content of those files?

Possible?

Comment: Get EasyFind from the app store [but software recs are off-topic, so I'm feeling generous ;-))

Comment: You may also find answers more quickly about MacOS X issues at https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't the files show up in Spotlight if you search for the text? Or in Finder search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure about any application however you could probably use `grep` for that search.

You can open the Terminal application, then type 
`cd /path/to/folder/with/txts` then you can run 
`grep -nR "string to search" *.txt`

This will search for the string inside all the .txt files inside the folder recursively.